# MariaDB, problem with [SELECT MAX(campo) +1 FROM...] and many users consulting

Tags: select, max, mariadb

I have the following problem in MariaDB.

From 2 different parts they make a query to generate a correlative for a document.

`SELECT MAX(campo) +1 as nuevo FROM TABLA WHERE ....;`

and then insert the record with the new correlative.

It turns out that several times it happens that they perform the same operation at the same time and it generates the same correlative for different documents.

Is there any way to avoid this situation?

*I can not use AUTO_INCREMENT because the correlative requires a condition. In this case, there would be many tables to replace different correlatives.*

Thank you.

Comment: I don't even understand your question in English.  Please edit your question and translate to English.  Then, add sample data.

Comment: Read about `AUTO_INCREMENT`.